# Index Match Multiple Criteria in Excel, looking at a partial match

Tags: excel, indexing, excel-formula, match

User Form Input

[image]

Loading Kit Reference

[image]

I have several columns of user input which needs to match each column in a reference sheet to return a given drawing number.

My initial attempt:

`=INDEX('Loading Kits'!A$2:A$113,MATCH(1,('Shop Orders'!B5='Loading Kits'!C$2:C$113)*('Shop Orders'!E5='Loading Kits'!D$2:D$113)*('Shop Orders'!G5='Loading Kits'!E$2:E$113)*('Shop Orders'!H5='Loading Kits'!F$2:F$113)*('Shop Orders'!I5='Loading Kits'!G$2:G$113),0))`

This works great when reference sheets only have one option for size ('Shop Orders'!B5='Loading Kits'!C$2:C$113). 
How do I create a match when there are several (up to 6) options listed in one column delimited by commas (24C,24D,26A,26B,26AV,26BV)?

Comment: There is a bit too much going on in this question with links to ideas rather than implementation, script, and errors/issues you are receiving.  I am listing as `too broad` as a closing-reason.  Please [edit your post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58492541/edit) to provide appropriate information about what you've tried (including your code if you have VBA activating to index/match when the userform is completed) and what errors you are receiving.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the few exceptions where I would say concatenation while using `INDEX` and `MATCH` would be safe to work with IF your values are concatenated through comma's without a space (otherwise the formula would be a little bit different). But let me give you a minimal example of how to get something like that to work:

[image]

The formula in `F3`:

```
=INDEX(A2:A4,MATCH(1,INDEX((B2:B4=F1)*(ISNUMBER(FIND(","&F2&",",","&C2:C4&","))),),0))
```

If your values follow eachother by comma space you obviously have to concatenate differently:

```
=INDEX(A2:A4,MATCH(1,INDEX((B2:B4=F1)*(ISNUMBER(FIND(", "&F2&",",", "&C2:C4&","))),),0))
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed! Thanks!

Just because I'm curious - what would the difference be if there is a space after the comma?

Comment: @Tahni, then it would simply not find the value =). Have all values concatenated the same way to avoid values not found!